# got undefined with Puppeteer while scraping Youtube playlist

Tags: node.js, youtube, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to scrape data from YouTube playlist but can not got any data.
I have tried code with browser and use Query Selector but want to automate this process and generate json file as output of this process.

code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


(async () => {
    console.log("begin");
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless : false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    console.log("after newPage");
    await page.goto('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2-FkZlJhxqVXZO1c6gKgsAdiet0zcOAO');

    console.log("after goto ");

    const selectorA = "a.yt-simple-endpoint.ytd-playlist-video-renderer"
    await page.waitForSelector(selectorA);
    console.log("after waitForSelector ");

    const items = await page.$$eval(selectorA, rows => {
        console.log("eval " + rows);
         return rows;    
    });

    console.log("items " + items);


    await browser.close();
})();
```

results

```
begin
after newPage
after goto 
after waitForSelector 
items undefined
```

Screenshot from same selector with broswer
[image]

[image]

Comment: `$$eval()` should return something serializable. Currently you attempt to return DOM elements. If you want to have the elements inside your NodeJS environment, use `$$()`.

Comment: It seems that it does not  work as console.log not called. @Sirko
u said that it return serializable but i got undefined

Comment: I said you **should** return something serializable. Basically anything that is meaningful when you pass it through `JSON.stringify()`. DOM elements can not be serialized like that, so I assume that this is the problem here.

Comment: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRXzW-o-zqs) at 9.35 use eval and got data

Comment: Ok, that part was just a guess, but you can also see in the video, that he got no meaningful result. I checked the playlist and selector you are using and in my browser they return no results. Maybe the issue is a mistake with the selector?

Comment: I have added a screenshot with playlist and same selector with browser @Sirko

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214578/discussion-between-sirko-and-mahmoud-mabrok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, various eval functions can transfer only serializable data (roughly, the data JSON can handle, with some additions). Your code returns an array of DOM elements, which are not serializable (they have methods and circular references). Try to retrieve the data in the browser context and returns only serializable data. For example:

```js
return rows.map(row => [row.innerText, row.href]);
```

Comment: It worked. But why console.log message not displayed?

Comment: `console.log()` inside `page.$$eval()` is called in browser context, so it output its data in the browser DevTools console.

Comment: Could u recommend a resource to deal with puppeteer

Comment: Sorry, I've only used and still use its doc: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md